# Utility to load .sys driver on Windows

Tags: windows, driver

Is there any tool that I can use to load .sys driver. I just made hallo world driver from this tutorial
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/24166-windows-driver-development-tutorial/ 
but I don't know how to load it.
Cant find anything on google.

Comment: CreateService() with the SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER option.

Comment: Yes, I found lot of code examples, but I need some kind of tool.

Comment: sc.exe, built into all recent versions of Windows.

Comment: Hi, I built a howto on that topic: http://jtsoft.at/load-windows-driver/

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices - You have `sc.exe` as Harry said in his comment, or you have the [OSR Loader](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157), which is what I personally use.

Keep in mind that, on Windows Vista/7 x64 you will need to use BCDEdit to enable **TESTSIGNING** (`bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING on`) in order to install your unsigned driver for development.

The program itself is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 x64 and I enabled `Test Signing`. But when I try to load my driver with OSR Loader I get an error message:  `this driver has been blocked from loading`
Any help?

Comment: x64 Windows prevents loading of unsigned drivers. The only way around it is disabling Patch Guard.